# BLE Connection between Bluetooth 4.2 and 4.0

Tags: bluetooth

I would like try to connect two devices via BLE classes and i found the following Website for reference

[Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

And before i am starting with programming the classes i wanted to know if ist even possible to connect a Bluetooth 4.2 and a Bluetooth 4.0 device together?

Because of i have a MCU with Bluetooth 4.2 and a Tablet with 4.0 and i am trying to write an app to connect those two devices.

I've already tried to connect an Iphone with Bluetooth 4.2 to my MCU and this is working but with my Tablet i get the message "Connect has been declined by the other device" (i still try it outside of my app and only on the android System under Settings).

Maybe this is the totally wrong community but i've just wanted to give it a try maybe somebody has an answer for that

Comment: They are fully compatible. Try to use a sniffer or check Bluetooth hci log file to see what's going on.

Comment: i'll give it a try thank you.